# How to add Dump to MySQL Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

I was asking my friend to provide dump of MySQL and he gave these 3 files with name `xxx.frm, yyy.MYD and zzz.MYI` . My concern is how can i add these to my MySQL workbench.

I have MySql in my Laptop and open in administrator where it shows import dump. I did but it shows error failed with exit code 1.

I am new bibe to SQL. Help me out here.

Comment: @case1352 how can i know they are dumps? and when i googled how to open .myd file. it shows Main source MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Ask for a .sql fie. Then import this in mysql.

You can read instructions how to import a .sql file here

http://www.ehow.com/how_8607107_import-sql-mysql.html